# Bitwise calculations not matching between calculator and Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation

[image]

[image]

Does not appear to make any sense, have tried multiple calculators.

Maybe something involving twos complement?

http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/
http://www.convertforfree.com/bitwise-calculator/

Comment: How do you think we can help? Show us the relevant business logic of the two calculators please.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `&` operator for [bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND), instead of the `&&` operator.

For example:

```
console.log(0x11 & 0x0F);
1
```